# how to change picture while object in moving

Tags: c, winapi

For example Pacman. Mouth either closed or opened. And while it is moving this pictures change each other.
I was trying to do like this

```
 case WM_PAINT:         
 ......
 if (ChoosePictureInt==0)
    {         
         MaskBlt(mdc,my_pos.x,my_pos.y,my_size.cx,my_size.cy,my_dc,0,0,my_closemask,0,0,MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY,SRCPAINT));
         MaskBlt(mdc, my_pos.x, my_pos.y, my_size.cx, my_size.cy, my_dc, 0, 0, my_mask, 0, 0, MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY, SRCPAINT));

    }
```

But as a result I've got only last picture in window.
When I  want to do like this(in case WM_TIMER)

```
 case WM_TIMER: 
     if(LOWORD(wParam) == 777u) {  
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
      {
         if (GreatFuncLeftRight(my_pos.x,my_pos.y))
         { 
            ChoosePictureInt = 1;
            if (ChooseMouseInt == 0)
                ChooseMouseInt = 0;
            else ChooseMouseInt = 0;
            my_pos.x -= 2;  // влево
                      MaskBlt(mdc, my_pos.x, my_pos.y, my_size.cx, my_size.cy, my_dc, 0, 0, my_mask, 0, 0, MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY, SRCPAINT));
         }
         else my_pos.x-=0;
      }
```

nothing happens

my answer

That's how I've solved this problem(I don't think it the best way)

```
//for examp. for -> direction 
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
      {
         if (GreatFuncLeftRightReverse(my_pos.x,my_pos.y))
         {
                            ChoosePictureInt = 0; //variable for picture with direction
            ChooseMouseInt *=-1; //variable for closed or opened mouth
            my_pos.x += 5;  // вправо
         }
         else my_pos.x+=0;
      }
```

And this is event in WM_PAINT

```
......
if (ChoosePictureInt==0)
    {         
      if(ChooseMouseInt<0)
      {
          Sleep(85);
         MaskBlt(mdc,my_pos.x,my_pos.y,my_size.cx,my_size.cy,my_dc,0,0,my_mask,0,0,MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY,SRCPAINT));
      }
      else
      {
          Sleep(85);
         MaskBlt(mdc, my_pos.x, my_pos.y, my_size.cx, my_size.cy, my_dc4, 0, 0, my_closemask, 0, 0, MAKEROP4(SRCCOPY, SRCPAINT));
      }
    } 
.....
```

Comment: Don't paint in your WM_TIMER handler. Only paint in WM_PAINT.

Answer (score 2):

Change state variables (like object coordinates, active bitmap etc.) in WM_TIMER message handler, and invalidate the window. Make all drawing in WM_PAINT message handler.

Use InvalidateRect function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx to invalidate window client area. This cause WM_PAINT message to be sent to the window, and WM_PAINT message handler redraws the window according to new object state.

Comment: But I use. 
               ` if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    {
    if (GreatFuncUpDownReverse(my_pos.x,my_pos.y))
    {
                   ChoosePictureInt = 3;
       ChooseMouseInt *=-1;
       my_pos.y += 2;  
    }
    else my_pos.y+=0;
    }
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);`

Comment: This is not what I see in your question. Please post your last code version, and describe what happens exactly. Remove all drawing code from WM_TIMER message handler. Also, handle keyboard keys in keyboard message handlers, and not in WM_TIMER.

Comment: It's rather big code, but after all directions I use IvalidateRect before `break`.But problem is solved.